# No connection with XBee radios on Arduino board

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

I have two Arduino boards which I've attached XBee radio boards to. One is to send data via `Serial.write(num)`, where `num` is an integer. The other is receiving that integer via `Serial.read`. However, when I have both units running, nothing is ever received by the receiving unit. I've tried switching the receiving unit radio board to the USB mode so that I can use the serial monitor to send data to the unit. I've tried sending bytes `01111110`, as well as integers such as `77`. Nothing ever gets read from the serial monitor. I've downloaded XCTU, but it cannot find either of the radios. What can I do?